# grey out checkbox2 and checkbox3 unless checkbox1 = true

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word

Another VBA dilemma for you.

I have checkbox1, checkbox2 and checkbox3.
I would like checkbox2 and checkbox3 to be greyed out if checkbox1=true
I have used a code similar for greying out a textbox

```
    Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim en As Boolean
    en = Not CheckBox1.Value
    EnableControls Array(tbappgn, tbappfn), en

'utility sub: enable/disable controls
Private Sub EnableControls(cons, bEnable As Boolean)
    Dim con
    For Each con In cons
        With con
            .Enabled = bEnable
            .BackColor = IIf(bEnable, vbWhite, RGB(200, 200, 200))
        End With
    Next con
End Sub
```

Just having an issue with getting the same code to work on other checkboxes.

Can add the checkbox numbers to the code above but I don't want that checkbox to be the trigger to grey/un grey the other checkboxes

something like this but with the correct terms.

```
Private Sub CheckBox11_Click()
 Dim en As Boolean
   en = Not CheckBox11.Value
    EnableControls Array(checkbox12, checkbox13), en

    Private Sub CheckBox15_Click()
    Dim en As Boolean
    en = Not CheckBox15.Value
    EnableControls Array(checkbox16, checkbox17), en

Private Sub EnableControls(cons, bEnable As Boolean)
    Dim con
    For Each con In cons
        With con
            .Enabled = bEnable
            .BackColor = IIf(bEnable, vbWhite, RGB(200, 200, 200))
        End With
    Next con
End Sub
```

Comment: see above code for desired end result haha. sorry the code just wont look nice in here.

Comment: Could you not just uncheck any other checkbox, once you find one checked?

Comment: basically I want 
checkboxa=false (checkbox 1, 2 and 3 greyed out)
checkboxb=false (checkbox 4, 5 and 6 greyed out) etc.
I want checkboxa+b to ungrey the other checkboxes if they =true.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here.  What is meant by "with the correct terms" ?

Comment: Don't worry -.-'' the code works now but didn't 5 minutes ago. I hate coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're asking for? When checkbox1 is true, the other will be grey... and vice versa...

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        CheckBox2.Enabled = False
        CheckBox3.Enabled = False
    Else
        CheckBox2.Enabled = True
        CheckBox3.Enabled = True
    End If        
End Sub
```

Comment: Nah the code I posted above works now but it wasn't working before and I couldn't figure out why. thank you for posting the above code though can use that somewhere for sure! :)